# How many points are needed to define a circumference?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

This doubt comes from a combinatorics problem in a textbook, which states:

> Consider two strictly parallel lines and seven dots, four of which are over one of them, and three over the other. Three dots are chosen at random: what is the probability that they define a circumference?

It turns out, the solution is $1-{{4\choose3}+1\over{7\choose3}}$. That is, all combinations in which the three chosen dots aren't collinear, divided by all combinations of three dots.

My question is: why mustn't they be collinear?

Comment: If three dots are collinear, that means they are on the same straight line. That straight line can't have more than two points in common with any given circle.

Comment: isn't a line like a circle with infinite radius

Comment: @SikFengCheong There are contexts where you would consider lines to be infinite-radius circles (like when using the flat plane as a model for hyperbolic or projective geometry), but this is not one of them.

Comment: The numerator in the "solution," $1-{4\choose3}+1$, is negative. I think you meant $$1-{{4\choose3}+1\over{7\choose3}}$$

Comment: Have you already seen collinear points on a circle ?

Answer (score 1):

If three collinear points $ABC$ belong to a circle, then there exists a point $O$ such that $$AO=BO=CO.$$

Let's show this is not possible. From the above equality it follows that $OAB$ and $OAC$ are two isosceles triangles, hence 
$$
\angle OAB=\angle OBA =\angle OCB.
$$
But then, in triangle $OBC$ we have an external angle $\angle OBA$ equal to internal angle $\angle OCB$, and that is impossible by [Euclid's exterior angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_angle_theorem), QED.